# What are Antecedent & Consequent Phrases in Music?

Tags: terminology, musical-forms

I've never heard the terms before:

**Antecedent and consequent** phrases

they seem to be elements of a period. It seems to be evident that I am not the only one ...

Comment: We're a bit like scientists and mathematicians. Why use ordinary words when you can baffle brains with unusual esoteric ones instead..?

Comment: I think it's the wrong attempt to make music more "scientificial".
in German it's called *Vordersatz and Nachsatz*.

Comment: Might be so, but German often uses long words!

Comment: I used to think that language could easily be simplified, but I'm starting to think that, in English at least, neologisms formed from English roots like "before-phrase" and "after-phrase” are confusing to hear and confusing to read, because it doesn't stand out from the nontechnical language, and doesn't fit with other related technical words. I suspect that German and other synthetic languages would have a better time with this (so I envy them.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer repeats a lot of what I wrote in... [Where is the antecedent and consequent phrase in this melody?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85086)

My understanding is *antecedent and consequent* are the two parts of a *period.*

The two parts are defined by *cadences.*

The antecedent can end with a variety of cadences but not a perfect cadence in the main key/tonic. The typical thing is some kind of cadence on the dominant chord of the main key.

The consequent ends on a perfect cadence in the main key.

My understanding of the theory is a period sets up tension in the antecedent by cadencing somewhere that isn't the tonic then later resolves that tension in the consequent by a cadence confirming the tonic. The idea is to create *structural dissonance.*

In the case of a simple period the structural dissonance is resolved quickly because the second phrase - the consequent - goes to a cadence in the tonic. You can compare that to a sonata structure which also starts with a kind of antecedent, a cadence on the dominant, but then the structural dissonance is hugely elaborated with other phrases cadencing in other keys before finally recapitulating with a final cadence on the tonic.

Periods are found through out classical music. Here is one (Mozart K.331)...

[image]

...mm. 1-4 are the antecedent and end on a half cadence `I6/4 V` while mm. 5-8 are the consequent and end on a perfect cadence `I6/4 V7 I`.

This particular melody exhibits *parallel* properties meaning that the antecedent and consequent use the same basic melody with slight variation. While many periods are parallel in shape the parallel shape should *not* be confused with period structure. The two-part antecedent/consequent structure of a period is defined by the *cadences ending the phrases!*

Answer (score 3):

*A period is one type of theme, like the sentence, common to the Classical style.*

*The period is generally eight measures long and contains two four-measure phrases, called **antecedent and consequent**.*

http://openmusictheory.com/period.html

2 fine examples are posted in this link:

https://mramusicplace.net/2016/02/26/what-are-antecedent-consequent-phrases-in-music/

Comment: (But the Mozart example on that website is *not* a period structure, but a sentence; yikes!)

Comment: or as Goethe says in Faust: "What you have in black and white,
you can safely carry home"

Comment: @Richard, that Mozart Sym. 40 example is not a period, because there isn't the two cadence structure? Even though the opening melody has a 4+4 parallel shape.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Those two Mozart examples are the two basic ideas of a larger sentence structure.